# where do i find net tools documentation (or) user manual?

Tags: documentation

i am trying to find user manual of net tools on ubuntu,i tried it on google,but i couldn't found any manual for net tools,i got to hear that it is alternative for Fiddler,i 've installed nettool-4.7.2
thank u in advance

Comment: I'd start with http://nettool.sourceforge.net/